# MySQL C++ Connector crashes at ResultSet->getBlob()

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to find out how to store binary data from a C++ program in a MariaDB database and restore from there.
For a first try I created a db table DOCUMENT:

```
idDOCUMENT INT(10)  PK
TYPE VARCHAR(45)
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(45)
CREATIONDATE DATETIME
DATA LONGBLOB
```

The binary data shall go to the DATA field.
Now I try to upload a PDF document to that table using this C++ code:

```
    ifstream inFile("/home/thomas/Projekte/test-and-trials/test-and-trials/Contract.pdf", ios::binary);
    const string INSERTtoDocument = "INSERT INTO DOCUMENT(TYPE,DESCRIPTION,DATA) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    shared_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> insertDocument(con->prepareStatement(INSERTtoDocument));
    insertDocument->setString(1, "PDF");
    insertDocument->setString(2, "Contract");
    insertDocument->setBlob(3, &inFile);
    int code = insertDocument->executeUpdate();
```

After executing that I can see in MySQL workbench that a new record has been created.
I can even download the blob from there, view the file in a PDF viewer. diff says that this download is binary same to what I uploaded.

Next I try to download the file using this C++ code:

```
    const string QUERYblob = "SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT WHERE idDOCUMENT=?";
    shared_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> selectDocument(con->prepareStatement(QUERYblob));
    selectDocument->setUInt(1, 12);
    shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res(selectDocument->executeQuery());
    res->first();
    string docType = res->getString("TYPE");
    string docDescr = res->getString("DESCRIPTION");
    istream *blobStream = res->getBlob("DATA");
```

string docType = res->getString("TYPE"); 
returns "PDF". Correct so far.
string docDescr = res->getString("DESCRIPTION"); 
gives me "Contract". Also fine.

But
istream *blobStream = res->getBlob("DATA"); 
crashes with a segment violation. Reliably, each and every time.

Whats going on here?

bt full shows:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6f7ba50 in __memcpy_ssse3 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007ffff6f7ba50 in __memcpy_ssse3 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007ffff7b939f7 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ffff7b97658 in sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::getString(unsigned int) const () from /usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff7b9391c in sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::getString(sql::SQLString const&) const () from /usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff7b97f98 in sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::getBlob(sql::SQLString const&) const () from /usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x0000000000401987 in main () at ../test-and-trials/main.cpp:49
        driver = 0x618290
        con = std::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> (use count 1, weak count 0) = {
          get() = 0x63a500}
        res = std::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> (use count 1, weak count 0) = {
          get() = 0x636b20}
        docDescr = "Contract"
        buf = std::shared_ptr<char> (empty) = {
          get() = 0x6 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x6>}
        docType = "PDF"
        outFile = <incomplete type>
        QUERYblob = "SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT WHERE idDOCUMENT=?"
        selectDocument = std::shared_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> (use count 1, weak count 0) = {get() = 0x63bde0}
        blobStream = 0x402d90 <__libc_csu_init>
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
        blobSize = 0
        __FUNCTION__ = "main"
(gdb)
```

Comment: If you can reduce your code sample to the smallest bit that reproduces your problem, you'll probably get more responses. Few people will tackle such a large code sample to help you.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace after compiling with `-g` and running under gdb? Which connector/C version?

Comment: 'bt full' in gdb too. Local vars may help.

Comment: reduced the Code to David Hempy's suggestion

Comment: compiled with -g and executed in gdb. Got the Segment Violation, but no core file :-(

Comment: the cppconn versin I use is that what Comes with openSuSE Leap 15.1: libmysqlcppconn7 Version 1.1.9-lp151.4.3.1